# where is the jitsi log?

Tags: macos, software, logs, path, voice

On Linux, I can "tail" the [jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) log:

```
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ tail .jitsi/log/jitsi0.log.0
00:08:08.579 WARNING: [59] service.resources.AbstractResourcesService.getSettingsInt().596 Missing resource for key: net.java.sip.communicator.SIP_PREFERRED_SECURE_PORT
00:08:26.710 INFO: [73] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been stopped
00:08:27.738 INFO: [73] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been stopped
00:10:08.444 WARNING: [76] plugin.sipaccregwizz.SIPAccountRegistrationWizard.installAccount().419 An account for id thufir@getonsip.com was already installed!
00:11:13.905 WARNING: [77] service.resources.AbstractResourcesService.getSettingsInt().596 Missing resource for key: net.java.sip.communicator.SIP_PREFERRED_CLEAR_PORT
00:11:13.907 INFO: [77] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been started
00:11:13.913 WARNING: [77] service.resources.AbstractResourcesService.getSettingsInt().596 Missing resource for key: net.java.sip.communicator.SIP_PREFERRED_SECURE_PORT
00:11:44.729 SEVERE: [90] impl.protocol.sip.SipRegistrarConnection.processResponse().937 Received an error response (400)
00:11:44.817 INFO: [90] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been stopped
00:11:45.818 INFO: [90] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been stopped
thufir@tleilax:~$
```

However, I wasn't able to find a `.jitsi` directory specifically, or configuration files for user applications.  Are they generally in the home folder?  Specifically, where's the jitsi configuration and log, please?

My system:

```
  System Version:   OS X 10.10.2 (14C1510)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 14.1.0
  Boot Volume:  Mac OSx
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Computer Name:    A MacBook Pro
  User Name:    thufir (thufir)
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
  Time since boot:  1:03
```

Answer (score 4):

**Jitsi → Preferences**, then selecting the “Advanced” tab and opening the “Logging” form. You’ll see the “Archive Logs” button in there.
[image]
If your `jitsi` version is above 2.4 or newer, you can find log files in `~/Library/Logs/Jitsi`.